# What does ? : mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does this line of code do?

```
len = ( s.length>t.length ) ? s.length : t.length
```

Comment: It's an in-line conditional.  `<condition> ? <true value> : <false value>` and is supported in many languages.

Answer (score 7):

?: is the ternary operator. It returns a value based on a condition.

```
x = (condition)?(if-true):(if-false)
```

So if condition is true, x is the value in the if-true section, and if it's false, then x is the value in if-false.

If is equivalent to what Corv1nus said earlier.

Answer (score 5):

It's the equivalent of `len = Math.max( s.length, t.length );` using the [ternary conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 4):

It sets the variable `len` to the length of string `s`, or the length of string `t`, depending on which is longer.

Comment: can you be sure that len is global?

Comment: No, you can't. If a previous line declared `var len`, then it's local.

Comment: @Joe okay, point. Removing that.

Answer (score 2):

If `s.length` is greater than `t.length` set `len = s.length` else `set len = t.length`

Answer (score 2):

That is using the conditional operator, which is also known as a ternary because it takes three operands.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator for more info.

You can find this construct with the same syntax in PHP, C, C++ and other languages, too.

Answer (score 1):

it is the equivalent of:

```
var len=0;
if(s.length>t.length)
  len= s.length;
else
  len=t.length;
```

So it's just a short way do doing if else.

Comment: Actually, the original didn't have `var`, so this isn't equivalent -- you're declaring a local variable, while the original may have been using a global.

Comment: May have a global variable but may not have, it may be inside a function and global vars is not best practice programming so that's the best practice equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It is doing this:

```
if (s.length > t.length) {
    len = s.length;
} else {
    len = t.length;
}
```

Comment: The original didn't have `var`, so this isn't equivalent -- you're declaring a local variable, while the original may have been using a global.

Answer (score 0):

len will be assigned the length of either s or t depending on which one has a greater length

Answer (score 0):

If the length of s is greather than the length of t, make "len" the length of s.
If the length of s is less than or equal to the length of t, make "len" the length of t.