# What does this line of javascript mean?

Tags: javascript, properties

I just opened Retina.js in hopes of learning a few things, but I'm stumped on the first line.

`var root = (typeof exports === 'undefined' ? window : exports);`

What exactly does this line do?

Further down,

```
 function Retina() {}

 root.Retina = Retina;
```

How was the Retina property set out of root without defining it first?

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand in that line? Do you know what the `typeof` operator does? Do you know what the conditional operator is? (`a ? b : c`).

Comment: [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ? : mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168981/what-does-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` is an operator that, when used on a variable that’s not defined at all, will still result in the value `'undefined'`. So the expression:

```
(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? window : exports)
```

checks whether `exports` isn’t in scope. If it isn’t, it results in `window` (the global object in browsers), and if it is, it results in `exports` (a standard name for exporting *things* from [sort of] modules – see [Relation between CommonJS, AMD and RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs)). The result is then assigned to `root`.

In case you were wondering about the conditional operator,

```
var d = a ? b : c;
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
var d;

if (a) {
    d = b;
} else {
    d = c;
}
```

As for `root.Retina = Retina;`, like with every other property in JavaScript, there’s no need to declare it and there is no facility to declare it.

Comment: You got my question spot on! I was looking for an explanation on the logic of exports. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of exports equals 'undefined', then we set it to window. Otherwise, we set it to exports.

Its ternary, you could do it this way :

```
if(typeof(exports) === 'undefined') 
root = window;
else 
root = exports
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var root = (typeof exports === 'undefined' ? window : exports);
```

This line checks if `exports` is not `undefined`. In Node.js environment, `exports` special variable refers to the current module. So, if `exports` is not defined, you are in a browser otherwise Node.js environment.

So, if you are in a browser, `root` will refer `window` object otherwise, the current module object(`exports`). `root.Retina` assigns the `Retina` function to either the window or the current module.