# What does this line mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, computer-science

X=(x=== images.length-1) ? 0 : x+ 1;

Please help me I have no idea, and it's for a school task that I have to hand in.

Comment: Do they teach researching in the school at all? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Good idea to read up on ternary statements if it's for school, you never know when you might need them in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question Mark in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Comment: It means the author didn't realize they could use the [remainder operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-mod-operator) for that: `x = (x + 1) % images.length;`

Comment: the title of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168981/what-does-mean-in-javascript) seems to be more on point it's marked as a dupe to something not-as-helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why people are so opposed to just answering the question. It's a ternary operation. It's a shortcut for an if/else clause. For this particular operation,

Is x equivalent (===) to images.length-1?  If so, set X to 0. Otherwise, set X to x + 1.

This pattern is likely used to endlessly iterate over an array (images). Once it reaches the end, it resets to the first element in the array.

Comment: Thank you so much, your help is really appreciated @gergi

Comment: And we have answered it. There are _three_ comments that have direct links to answers. Two of them are duplicate questions. Another comment directly states this is a ternary operator. What more information is needed here?

Comment: I'm confused because I know the answer has been answered and I have not asked for anymore information so why does it seem like you have a problem.